# Not able to perfrom git checkout . Facing error- Fatal: Reference is not a tree error is triggering

Tags: github, fatal-error, git-checkout

I am new to github and when i tried to checkout initial `6.2` from the link mentioned below i am getting below error.

link: https://github.com/trainindata/deploying-machine-learning-models/commits/master

```
error :  fatal : reference is not a tree 75b48f55a9b6dd94c40846f5a66c7f217a1f580b
```

can anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try and clone first, then checkout: it does work:

```
D:\git\tests>git clone https://github.com/trainindata/deploying-machine-learning-models
Cloning into 'deploying-machine-learning-models'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 538, done.
Receivinremote: Total 538 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 538
Receiving objects: 100% (538/538), 1.33 MiB | 1.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (175/175), done.

D:\git\tests>cd deploying-machine-learning-models

D:\git\tests\deploying-machine-learning-models>git checkout 75b48f55a9b6dd94c40846f5a66c7f217a1f580b
Note: switching to '75b48f55a9b6dd94c40846f5a66c7f217a1f580b'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 75b48f5 Section 6.2 - Initial setup
```